# links sent from my website email give "suspicious link" warning in gmail although the mail is not spam

Tags: email, security, gmail

When I send an a confirmation mail from my web site email to an email at gmail, it reaches the inbox normally but when I click on the link it gives a warning "suspicious link".

I tried to send the same link from my personal email but the warning didn't show.

also when I forwarded the same message sent from my website email to another email, the warning didn't show.

Any ideas what may be the reason.

Comment: I got the same. It's this popup right? https://cloudup.com/ceEHKCAteSP. I am using SendGrid, and you?

Comment: I had the same issue. If you get an answer. That would be nice.

Comment: I think this article can be helpful: https://www.tinywebhut.com/suspicious-link-message-in-gmail-50